# Expanding a non-singleton dimension in PyTorch, but without copying data in memory?

Tags: python, pytorch

Say that we have a tensor `s` of size `[a,b,c]` that is not necessarily contiguous, and `b>>1`.

I want to expand (but not copy) it in the second dimension for n times to get a tensor of size `[a,nb,c]`.

The issue is that I cannot find a way to do this without explicitly copying data in memory.
The ways I know to do the operation, including

```
s.repeat_interleave(n,dim=1)
s.unsqueeze(-2).expand(-1,-1,n,-1).contiguous().view([a,-1,c])
s.unsqueeze(-2).expand(-1,-1,n,-1).reshape([a,-1,c])
```

will perform the copying step, and significantly slow things down.

Anyone know a solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible, and here is a minimal example to illustrate my point.

Consider a torch.Tensor `[1, 2, 3]`, which has size `(3,)`. If we want to expand it without performing a copy, we would create a new [view](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.view.html) of the tensor. Imagine for example that we want to create a view that contains twice the values of the original tensor, i.e. `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]` which would have size `(2*3,)`. But it is not possible to define such a view only playing with the strides, here is why: to step from `1` to `2`, or from `2` to `3`, we would need the stride value to be 1. But to step from `3` to `1`, we would need the stride value to be `-2`, but the system of strides as implemented cannot have different values for a given axis.

I am not 100% sure that it is not possible. Maybe there exists a very clever trick by using `storage_offset` parameter of `torch.as_strided()` function, or something else. Also, Perhaps this feature will be implemented in a future version, for example if you try to set a negative stride value, you have the error

```
>>> torch.as_strided(torch.tensor([1, 2, 3]), size=(1,), stride=(-1,))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: as_strided: Negative strides are not supported at the moment, got strides: [-1]
```

indicating that this functionality could change in the future (here I used pytorch version 1.13.0).

One could argue that you could first expand without copying in a new dimension using `torch.Tensor.expand()`, and then `flatten()` the result, but this does not work, let me explain why. In the documentation of [`expand()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.expand.html#torch.Tensor.expand), it is explained that this function returns a new `view` of the tensor (so this does not do any copy), and in the documentation of [`flatten()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.flatten.html), it is explained that this function will try to return a view of the flattened tensor, and if not possible it will return a copy. Then let's try this method, and check the memory size of the tensor at each step using `tensor.storage().nbytes()`:

```
>>> a = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3])
>>> print(a)
tensor([1, 2, 3])
>>> print(a.storage().nbytes())
24
>>> b = a.expand([2, 3])
>>> print(b)
tensor([[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]])
>>> print(b.storage().nbytes())
24
>>> c = b.flatten()
>>> print(c)
tensor([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3])
>>> print(c.storage().nbytes())
48
```

As we can see, `flatten()` does not seem capable to return a view of the flattened tensor since `c` takes twice memory compared to `a`. And if the pyTorch implementation of `flatten()` is not capable of doing that, this probably means that indeed it is not possible to do it.